# Select 5 random elements of table with specific value of sql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of questions in mysql with 5 different types of questions like follow :

```
table decouverte :
id |    question   |    answer    |    type   | date
----------------------------------------------------
1  | txt question1 |  theAnswer1  |    easy   | null
2  | txt question2 |  theAnswer2  |   normal  | null
3  | txt question3 |  theAnswer3  | difficult | null
4  | txt question4 |  theAnswer4  |    hard   | null
5  | txt question5 |  theAnswer5  |    easy   | null
.
.
```

I would like to get everyday at midnight one random question of each type where the date is either null or current date.
For the moment I have this :

```
 $stmt = $this->db->prepare("CREATE EVENT get_5_dailyQuestions
                                ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
                                DO SELECT * from decouverte where type = 'easy' AND (date is NULL OR date = CURDATE()) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 UNION
                                SELECT * from decouverte where type = 'normal' AND (date is NULL OR date = CURDATE()) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 UNION
                                SELECT * from decouverte where type = 'difficult' AND (date is NULL OR date = CURDATE()) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 UNION
                                SELECT * from decouverte where type = 'hard' AND (date is NULL OR date = CURDATE()) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

The create event works, but not the SELECT thing.
Can anyone help me ? Thank you in advance

Comment: I'd try this without any event, but instead just seed the RAND() function with a value that stays constant across the whole day (like the number of the day within the year for example.)

Comment: Not really sure what you expect a select statement will do in a scheduled event... The event performs the select, but its results will be discarded as there is nothing to consume it.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe, your answer works, however since I have never used seed before, I don't  know how to change the seed every day at midnight and I didn't find how to do it on internet. Do you have any idea how I can do this ?

Comment: If you make it dependent on the current date - then it _automatically_ changes at midnight :-) You could use `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%j')` to have it seeded with a value from 0 to 366, which will repeat each year. Or, if you don't want to get the same values on the same day of every year, then use `%Y%m%d` - that is `YYYYMMDD` format, and as such can still be interpreted as an integer to seed the rand function with.

Comment: We can calculate the random values on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would just create a result table to store the randomly generated data from the base table . Then we can query the result table. This is of course done in an event on a daily basis. Here is code written and tested in workbench. (I set the interval to 1 minute ) By the way, I made some adjustment to your query. Instead of 4 separate `SELECT` statements, we can accomplish the job in one.

```
set @@global.event_scheduler=on;
create table chosen_result like decouverte;
delimiter //
CREATE EVENT get_5_dailyQuestions
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 minute STARTS now() DO
BEGIN
truncate chosen_result;
insert chosen_result
select * from decouverte t1
 join
 (select (select id from decouverte where type=d.type order by rand() limit 1) as id
  from decouverte d
  where date is null or date=sysdate()
  group by type
  ) t2
  using(id);
END//   
delimiter ;
```